# Can't bulk insert file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I have a 5GB file that I need to bulk insert into a SQL Server database (2005 SP2).  When I attempt to do so (using a format file that worked in the past for the same import file), I get the error:

*The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases*

When I run the command

```
select log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where [name] = 'MyDB'
```

I get "ACTIVE_TRANSACTION", but there are no open transactions.

Following are things I've tried to no avail:

- Successfully shrunk data and log files
- Checked drive space: plenty.
- Tried on a database with multiple log files.
- Tried on a newly created database.
- Tried on a newly created database where I pre-allocated 10GB for both the data and log files.
- Restarted the service.

Comment: how ar eyou performing the bulk-insert?  are you using openrowset?

Comment: Did it work before for this specifie data file/format file/server, or only on some other server?

Comment: If tempdb is full, then check tempdb, not ur own database: select log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases where [name] = 'tempdb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the data-allocation size for Tempdb and try.

Comment: This was merely due to the fact that I was confusing tempdb with the database log file.  Tempdb was on a drive low on space.